# Multi index series into pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, aggregation

I have a pandas series with two indices:

```
df_agg=df.groupby(['yearID','teamID']).sum()['Salary']
df_agg.head()

yearID  teamID
1985    ATL       14807000
        BAL       11560712
        BOS       10897560
        CAL       14427894
        CHA        9846178
```

I want to convert int into a pandas data frame like

```
yearID     teamID    Salary
1985        ATL       14807000
1985        BAL       11560712
1985        BOS       10897560
1985        CAL       14427894
1985        CHA        9846178
```

I tired to use:

```
df_new=df_agg.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

but I got the following error:

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 df_new=df_agg.reset_index(inplace=True)

C:\Users\ameimand\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in reset_index(self, level, drop, name, inplace)
    966

```
    index=new_index).__finalize__(self)
    967         elif inplace:
--> 968             raise TypeError('Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series '
    969                             'to create a DataFrame')
    970         else:

TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there are 2 nice solutions parameter `as_index=False`:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['yearID','teamID'], as_index=False)['Salary'].sum()
```

Or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) without `inplace=True`:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['yearID','teamID'])['Salary'].sum().reset_index()
```

***Notice***:

Better is specify column for aggregation after `groupby` in `[]` like `['Salary']`:

```
df.groupby(['yearID','teamID'], as_index=False)['Salary']
```

as:

```
df.groupby(['yearID','teamID']).sum()['Salary']
```

because this aggregate all columns and then select only `Salary`.